# The Format of Body for a POST request in Web Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a web activity in azure data factory pipeline which have only one header and I have to pass body for a POST request. I have tried passing body as JSON and as String also but the request failed with "Invalid Query". Can anyone please tell me how can I send a POST request from azure data pipeline with additional header and body. I have multiple key value pairs to pass to body.[Check the Screenshot of web activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRKaG.png)

Comment: Do you have a link to the Web API documentation you are trying to call? Is it expecting a JSON payload or a form post encoding?

Comment: They have given this curl command to make request other than that there is no info provided. Here is the link: https://api.pharmaintelligence.informa.com/docs/#Authentication                  
curl -X POST https://identity.pharmaintelligence.informa.com/connect/token \
    -H 'Authorization: Basic {auth_token}'
    -F grant_type=password
    -F username={username}
    -F password={password}
    -F scope=customer-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this. First, add one more header with Name of `Content-Type` and value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Then change the Body to:

```
grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}&scope=customer-api
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked