API working fine in Postman but not in Web Activity of ADF
The POST request is working fine in Postman but is generating an error in the web activity of ADF. No parameters are being passed, and the Authorization setting is "Inherit auth from parent." Please find the more details of Postman in screenshots below.

URL and Header:

Postman JSON Body:

Postman JSON Output:


Following the same approach in the web activity of ADF, but every time I get the below error:

I am trying the following approach too for the Web activity:

Changed the Integration Runtime from AutoresolveIntegrationRuntime to SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime, but no luck.
Added "Bearer" and a space before the value of the app-token, but no luck.
Added Authorization as Header too and given the value as Bearer and a space with value of token.
Checked the JSON body with an online checker too.


Please, someone guide me on this. What am I missing here? The error itself says "user configuration issue." I have tried everything and experimented in various ways but am still stuck.

Look at this for how to supply the body for x-www-form-urlencoded and see if that solves it x-www-form-urlencoded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256158/the-format-of-body-for-a-post-request-in-web-activity-in-azure-data-factory

For Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
you need to give the body in below format.
name=test&salary=123&age=23
I can see you giving query value a json body and postman got the response.
So, you body should be like this
query={"name":"jai","salary":"123","age":"23"}
or
key value pair joined with equal sign(=) and each pair separated by ampersand(&).
Input:

Output:


After reviewing your answer, I included query={....} in the body of my web activity, and it worked perfectly. The pipeline ran successfully. Thank you!

i guess now you know, how to pass data for application/x-www-form-urlencoded
